# Check if function is called within solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have a really large `solution S` with several projects, `dll`s, etc.

I need to document which classes and methods from one `dll D` (which we have writen, it ia our dll with source code, almost ~500 functions) are actually used  within a `solution S`, so that I can get in my doc only functions that are actually used.

Is there any program/hack/solution to such a problem? Because 500 seems to be a large number, and using `"Find <function name> in entire solution"` manually seems hell to me.

Any ideas? How can I get some kind of `debug info`?

We are using `MCVS 2010`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the library `D` from the linking step and see how many unresolved external symbols you have. This would leave only functions defined in headers which you have to check by hand.

You could also see the library (if it exists) generated by `S` or its projects - most lib's have an import table which is a list of functions imported from other modules.

However, the issue here seems to be in the design of `D`. The public interface should be fully documented, but shouldn't expose what isn't necessary (no internal functions, no internal functionality). If it was like this, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: hwo can I view import table for `N.lib` file?

Comment: @Oleksandra I usually use the viewer from total commander, but there's also an utility called dumpbin iirc.

Comment: could you be more specific about total commander, please? Is it some kind of plugin?

Comment: I've googled. what plugin do I need to view .lib files in total commander? Or no plugin? Just the total commander itself?

Comment: @Oleksandra yep, the program itself. Just navigate to the lib and press F3. The built-in viewer should do the rest.

Comment: with what program does your TC viewer open .lib files? I got notepad++ - and it shows just a mess!

Comment: which section should I look for in the `Library Header` tab? where should the import table be?